# No me muestra cada elemento del array de response2

Tags: javascript, api

Lo que pretendo con este código es que en la lista se muestre marca y dinero , me refiero marca[0] debería ir asociado con money[0] , pero el problema es que en money solo me pilla el último elemento , y muestra 9 marcas de coches con el mismo money para los 9. ¿Cómo podría arreglarlo?

```
$http.get(api6).then(function(response) {
        $http.get(myApi).then(function(response2) {
            response2.data.forEach(function(item) {
                money = item.money;
                console.log(money);
            });

            response.data.Results.map(function(elem) {
                if (contador < 9) {
                    marcas = elem.Make_Name;
                    contador++;
                    lAux.push({ "marcas": marcas, "money": money });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto esta pasando porque estas reasignando el valor de `money` cada vez que ciclas con el loop, para solucionarlo simplemente haz que se introduzcan a tu array todos los datos dentro del mismo loop.

Este tipo de loop es bloqueante por lo que JS siempre va a esperar que termine el ciclado para continuar con el código, si tu asignas el valor de una variable dentro del loop esta siempre va a representar el ultimo valor iterado, por lo que debes trabajar lo que quieres todo dentro del mismo loop (x2), aquí te dejo un ejemplo utilizando la API de `fetch`.

```js
var output = []
fetch("https://uinames.com/api/?amount=25",{
  method:"GET",
  headers:{
    Accept:"application/json"
  }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(function(res){
  for (var i=0; i<res.length;i++) {
    var action = {nombre: res[i].name, genero: res[i].gender};
    output.push(action);
  }
  document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>"+JSON.stringify(output,null,2)+"</pre>"
});
```

Como ves todo está concatenado dentro del mismo loop, igualmente si fuesen respuestas de dos diferentes fuentes, simplemente haces el request de las dos y luego haces el loop.

> **EDIT**:

Independientemente del código de ejemplo de arriba me gustaría que te fijaras en la respuesta y no en la manera de obtener tus datos, es indiferente, como te comenté, aquí lo que esta pasando es los siguiente:

Observando en tu código puedes ver que estas realizando un ciclo con `forEach()` para asignar el valor de la variable `money`:

```
$http.get(api6).then(function(response) {
    $http.get(myApi).then(function(response2) {
        response2.data.forEach(function(item) {
            money = item.money; //<-------- Aquí está tu problema inicialmente.
            console.log(money);
        });

        response.data.Results.map(function(elem) {
            if (contador < 9) {
                marcas = elem.Make_Name;
                contador++;
                lAux.push({ "marcas": marcas, "money": money });
            }
        });
```

El problema está en que cuando haces esto, pasa que estas reasignando el valor de la variable cada vez que el ciclo se reinicia, por ejemplo ejecuta el siguiente código:

```js
var miArray = ["1","2","3"];
var money;

miArray.forEach(function(item){
  money = item
  document.body.innerHTML += "<p>El valor de la variable en el ciclo es: "+money+"</p>"
});

document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Pero el valor al finalizar el ciclo es: "+money+"</p>"
```

Como ves dentro del `forEach()` la variable cambia evidentemente, pero dado a que los ciclos en JS son bloqueantes al final cuando vas a ejecutar código después del mismo, JS esperará a que este termine de iterar los datos. Como puedes observar dentro del loop la variable `money` imprime el resultado esperado, pero cuando el ciclo termina y ejecutamos código fuera de este la variable `money` tendrá el valor del ultimo elemento en el array iterado en el loop, en este caso ya que se lo hemos asignado.

Entonces en tu código cuando requieres la variable `money` dentro del `map` ya se ha ejecutado el ciclo `forEach()` con anterioridad, equivaliendo al ultimo valor asignado en el ciclo, en resumen:

```
$http.get(api6).then(function(response) {
  $http.get(myApi).then(function(response2) {
    response2.data.forEach(function(item) {
        money = item.money; //<-------- Aquí está tu problema inicialmente.
        console.log(money);
    });

    response.data.Results.map(function(elem) {
        if (contador < 9) {
            marcas = elem.Make_Name;
            contador++;
            lAux.push({ "marcas": marcas, "money": money }); <----- // Aquí money equivale al ultimo valor del ciclco de arriba.
        }
    });
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: La verdad , no entiendo esta solución

Comment: Editaré y trataré de ser mas explicito ajaja